# CodeForces stones on table, code cannot pass one test case I cannot understand why

Tags: c++, string, if-statement, char, implementation

This is the question - There are n stones on the table in a row, each of them can be red, green or blue. Count the minimum number of stones to take from the table so that any two neighboring stones had different colors. Stones in a row are considered neighboring if there are no other stones between them.

Input - The first line contains integer n (1 ≤ n ≤ 50) — the number of stones on the table.

The next line contains string s, which represents the colors of the stones. We'll consider the stones in the row numbered from 1 to n from left to right. Then the i-th character s equals "R", if the i-th stone is red, "G", if it's green and "B", if it's blue.

Output - The answer

My code - ```

```
int main(){
    string s;
    int q,a,b,c;
    cin >> q;
    cin >> s;
    a = s.length();
    for(int i=0;i<q;i++){
            if((s[i]=='R'&&s[i+1]=='R')||(s[i]=='G'&&s[i+1]=='G')||(s[i]=='B'&&s[i+1]=='B')){
                s.erase(i+1,i+1);
            }
        }
    b = s.length();
    c = a - b;
    if((s[0]=='R'&&s[1]=='R')||(s[0]=='G'&&s[1]=='G')||(s[0]=='B'&&s[1]=='B')){
        cout << c+1;
       }else{ cout << c;
       }
}
```

When the input is "4 RBBR", the output shows 2 instead of 1, i'm not understanding why its doing that, could someone help me.
Here are some other test cases which my code passes -
"3
RRG"
"5
RRRRR"

Comment: You don't need `cin >> q` because `q = s.length()-1` which reduces potential input errors. You can also reduce the complicated if in the loop to `if(s[i] == s[i+1])`.

Comment: @Devolus Ive written cin >> q because thats the input format. Thanks for the advice on the if statement. The original problem still persists though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int main()
{
    string s;
    size_t q, a, c;
    cin >> q;
    cin >> s;
    a = s.length();

    // You may not use q here, because you are modifying the string length, so when the
    // loop enters the next iteration, q is no longer valid.
    // Since you are comparing it with the next item, you must reduce the count by 1, otherwise you read out of bounds.
    // It's also wrong to use q here, because the user can enter an invalid length. i.E. "5 RR".
    for (size_t i = 0; i < s.length()-1; i++)
    {
        if (s[i] == s[i + 1])
        {
            // Here 'i' may not be increased, because the next character can also be a neighbor now
            s.erase(i + 1, 1);
            i--;
        }
    }

    c = a - s.length();
    cout << c;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I understood it now. Also, could you explain what size_t datatype is? And also why the second parameter in .erase is 1?

Comment: If your instructor insists on using q you may talk to him about user input errors. :) Might either get you a + or a pissed of instructor. :)

Comment: `size_t` is the standard size for your platform. on 32 bit it is usually `uint32_t` and on 64 bit it is usually `uint64_t`, but this may vary depending on your architecture.

Comment: And why is the second parameter in .erase 1?

Comment: Because you want to erase only one element and not i+1 elements. It is the number of items, not the position. You can also use `s.erase(i+1)` instead.

Comment: Oh ok, I thought it was the position. Thanks

Comment: https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/